# Cannot give Focus to Flash Object via Keyboard in Firefox

Tags: flash

I am creating an accessible HTML Page with Flash Embedded Content. I want to be able to TAB thru all the Hyperlinks in the HTML side and embedded FLASH Buttons. on IE All the Tabbing works fine but NOT in Firefox.

In Firefox when I TAB, it simply Skips the Flash Content. I want to be able to add the Flash buttons to the TAB cycle.

I have tried adding the TABIndex Explicitly and then the TAB focus gets stuck on the Flash Object and I am Unable to TAB Thru to any other object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct it is known Firefox bug. It's not a flash issue.

Comment: Is there a documentation or a bug report filed so that I can show it to the client?

Comment: Try these [link1](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=401972) or [link2](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=401972)

Comment: Also I'm not sure, but maybe there are some workarounds for this.